# Extra Tor bridges

Tags: directory

Following the instructions on the Tor [Bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en#FindingMore) page, I sent an email  requesting some obfs4 bridges.
I received a reply saying "no bridges currently available."

Then I used the [BridgesDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/options) from my browser to request obfs4 bridges and was provided with **three**.
Obviously obfs4 bridges *are* available, so why didn't the email method send any?

Comment: What did you put in the message body? Which e-mail provider do you use? I just sent an e-mail via Gmail, and got bridges just fine, so the e-mail system is working properly.

Comment: @SuperSluether it's a usual censorship case: in Russia, for example, it's a big problem

Comment: But the email wasn't blocked, it just replied saying no bridges. So unless the government is spoofing emails but not blocking the bridges website.

Answer (score 1):

I just duplicated the first message to test, and received three bridges. Must have been a system glitch. The text in the body of the email both times was **get transport obfs4**. I no longer needed more bridges because I'd acquired a bunch by using the BridgesDB, but the three I received were new so I added them anyway. I assume the more bridges you have the better, and I now have plenty.

Comment: Glad to see you got it sorted.